# aws sns auto confirm subscription

Tags: amazon-sns

I have this terraform to auto confirm sns topic subscription alerts but it does not auto confirm and rather keep showing pending confirmation while sending emails to my inbox. Is there anything preventing this from happening?

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "aws_logins" {
  name = "aws-console-logins"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.aws_logins.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_topic_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["SNS:Publish"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    resources = [aws_sns_topic.aws_logins.arn]
  }
}

# Creates a subscription and subscript to the sns topic
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "guard_duty_findings" {
  topic_arn                       = aws_sns_topic.aws_logins.arn
  endpoint_auto_confirms          = true
  protocol                        = "email"
  endpoint                        = "......@gmail.com"
}
```

I have tried adding time out but time out only works for http and https protocol

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot auto confirm an email SNS subscription.

The definition of *endpoint_auto_confirms* is:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription#endpoint_auto_confirms

> **endpoint_auto_confirms** - (Optional) Whether the endpoint is capable of auto confirming subscription (e.g., PagerDuty). Default is
> false.

This only defines whether the endpoint is *capable* of auto confirming or not.

In fact, wait for confirmation is explicitly set to false in the code for the email protocols:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/503b118c9a0f91384010f0503e117d125c3ae9ab/internal/service/sns/topic_subscription.go#L182

```
waitForConfirmation := true

if !d.Get("endpoint_auto_confirms").(bool) && strings.Contains(d.Get("protocol").(string), "http") {
    waitForConfirmation = false
}

if strings.Contains(d.Get("protocol").(string), "email") {
    waitForConfirmation = false
}
```